# autocompletion in discord command with custom command prefix in python

Tags: python, discord

I am using discord.py library with fastAPI to create a discord bot.
I want to use a custom command prefix, let's say: /something and if my command is help so I want autocompletion for /sizzlegg help.

As I am using cogs as well, so without custom prefix I was able to get the autocmpletion using the hybrid_command functionality. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve the same for  **/something help**

My current code is as following:

```
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix='\something', intents=intents, strip_after_prefix=True
)


@commands.hybrid_command()
async def hello(
  ctx: commands.Context[Any],
  member: Optional[Union[discord.Member, None]] = None,
    ):
        """Says hello."""

   await ctx.send(f"Hello {member1.name}")
```